# Android OpenGL 2.0 ES Translate Matrix

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to create a simple Android OpenGL 2.0 game to get my feet wet. I refeered to Androids tutorial on OpenGL and got it up and running, moved my square to where I want it and now i'm trying to translate it with on touch.

I've read that I have to unproject the current square... but not understanding this. Below is my code if there is any help on performing a translation on the square...

```
 private float mPreviousY;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        // MotionEvent reports input details from the touch screen
        // and other input controls. In this case, you are only
        // interested in events where the touch position changed.
    float y = e.getY();

    switch (e.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            float dy = y - mPreviousY;

            // reverse direction of rotation to left of the mid-line
            if (y < getHeight() / 2) {
              dy = dy * -1 ;
            }

            mRenderer.mOffSet += dy;
            requestRender();
    }

    mPreviousY = y;
    return true;
}
```

my onDrawFrame:

```
    @Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {

    // Draw background color
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Set the camera position (View matrix)
    Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -50, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    Matrix.translateM(mModleViewProjMatrix, 0, 0, mOffSet, 0);

    // Calculate the projection and view transformation
    Matrix.multiplyMM( mModleViewProjMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0);

    // Draw square
    mPaddle.draw(mModleViewProjMatrix);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unprojecting means, reversing the process a vertex undergoes when being transformed. The forward transform is

```
v_eye = Modelview · v

v_clip = Projection · v_eye

v_ndc = v_clip / v_clip.w
```

Now what you have to do is reversing this process. I suggest you take a look at the sourcecode of the GLU function gluUnProject of Mesa, to be found here http://cgit.freedesktop.org/mesa/glu/tree/src/libutil/project.c

#### Update

Unprojecting is essentially reversing the process.

Let's look at Mesa's GLU gluUnProject code:

```
GLint GLAPIENTRY
gluUnProject(GLdouble winx, GLdouble winy, GLdouble winz,
        const GLdouble modelMatrix[16], 
        const GLdouble projMatrix[16],
                const GLint viewport[4],
            GLdouble *objx, GLdouble *objy, GLdouble *objz)
{
    double finalMatrix[16];
    double in[4];
    double out[4];
```

First the compund transformation `Projection · Modelview` is evaluated…

```
    __gluMultMatricesd(modelMatrix, projMatrix, finalMatrix);
```

…and inverted, i.e. reversed;

```
    if (!__gluInvertMatrixd(finalMatrix, finalMatrix)) return(GL_FALSE);

    in[0]=winx;
    in[1]=winy;
    in[2]=winz;
    in[3]=1.0;
```

Then the window/viewport coordinates are mapped back into NDC coordinates

```
    /* Map x and y from window coordinates */
    in[0] = (in[0] - viewport[0]) / viewport[2];
    in[1] = (in[1] - viewport[1]) / viewport[3];

    /* Map to range -1 to 1 */
    in[0] = in[0] * 2 - 1;
    in[1] = in[1] * 2 - 1;
    in[2] = in[2] * 2 - 1;
```

And multiplied with the inverse of the compound projection modelview

```
    __gluMultMatrixVecd(finalMatrix, in, out);
```

Finally it is checked, that the so called homogenous component is nonzero

```
    if (out[3] == 0.0) return(GL_FALSE);
```

And the homogenous divide inverted.

```
    out[0] /= out[3];
    out[1] /= out[3];
    out[2] /= out[3];
```

Resulting in the original vertex position prior to the projection process

```
    *objx = out[0];
    *objy = out[1];
    *objz = out[2];
    return(GL_TRUE);
}
```

Comment: I dont quiet understand what you mean. Can you elaborate a little bit more on the process? Like what is v_eye? v_clip? v_ndc? why we do it? etc?

Comment: @user1925639: This is the usual OpenGL transformation pipeline. It is essential that you understand the transformation steps performed on a vertex if you want to do 3D programming (using OpenGL or not). Please read this article and its followup for the details. You'll need them. http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Transformation – unprojecting is basically reversing the process.